# How to find&replace the last number if it appears

Tags: vba

I have a long document that needs to replace the last number if it appears at the end of the line.
But sometimes this number is mixed with a letter:a or b.

So how to get the number and at "<a>" tag it?

```
Text Line 1
Text Line
Text Line 20a
Text Line 300b
Text COVID-19 4000
```

To

```
Text Line <a href="../1.html">1</a>
Text Line
Text Line <a href="../20.html">20</a>a
Text Line <a href="../300.html">300</a>b
Text COVID-19 <a href="../4000.html">4000</a>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant application tag(s) to your post. You should also show us the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This custom Function will work.

```
Function findTheEndNumner(theText As String) As String
    Dim NewResult As String, finalResult As String, i As Long
    NewResult = Mid(theText, InStrRev(theText, " ", -1, vbTextCompare) + 1, 999)

    For i = 1 To Len(NewResult)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(NewResult, i, 1)) Then
            finalResult = finalResult & Mid(NewResult, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    findTheEndNumner = finalResult

End Function
```

You can test it with this macro:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox findTheEndNumner("Text Line 1")
    MsgBox findTheEndNumner("Text Line")
    MsgBox findTheEndNumner("Text Line 20a")
    MsgBox findTheEndNumner("Text Line 300b")
    MsgBox findTheEndNumner("Text COVID-19 4000")
End Sub
```

Sample file also available if you want... [download it here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4IzkMaD15IgpplfRQ?e=Eov3hG).